# How do I install Azure CLI for a Service Account on my build server

Tags: continuous-integration, bamboo, azure-cli

I have successfully installed Azure CLI on my build server and can use it at the command line. But when a build executes, running under a service account I get the following error:

**az : The term 'az' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script 
file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was 
included, verify that the path is correct and try again.**

I am assuming this is because Azure CLI was installed only for my user. The service account does not have an interactive login so I can't log in and install Azure CLI for that account. Is there a way to make Azure CLI available to my service account.

Comment: Hi, your build server is Windows OS?

Comment: I will test in my lab and update it.

Comment: Is a restart required? I have added the path to az in environment variables but still no dice. This is my workaround:
$msdeployArguments = ' login --service-principal -u xxxxxxx --password ${bamboo.azureManagementCertificatePath} --tenant xxxxxxx'
$commandLine = '&"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\CLI2\wbin\az.cmd" --% ' + $msdeployArguments
Invoke-Expression $commandLine

Comment: Same error log `az : The term 'az' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet`. The error log bamboo does not find az install path.

Comment: Do you mean you are getting the same error in your lab?

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your Path environment variable

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\CLI2\wbin
```

Comment: You mean add this to your PATH environment variable, as opposed to setting it to this, right? I imagine setting your PATH to just this would break a lot of things.